# Downsize the object memory by subsetting a data frame in R

Tags: r, subset, objectsize

So I'm using the database from https://www.kaggle.com/jiashenliu/515k-hotel-reviews-data-in-europe/downloads/515k-hotel-reviews-data-in-europe.zip/1 and I don't understand why I can't downsize the object size by subsetting the dataset

```
df = read.csv('Hotel_Reviews.csv')
object.size(df)
```

> 200503848 bytes

```
object.size(df[sample(1:nrow(df),500),])
```

> 157225848 bytes

By taking 0.1% of the data, I only downsized the data to 75%. I don't understand why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after looking more deeply at it, it seems it's because my data frame was made of factors and even by subsetting, it keeps the empty levels

```
df = read.csv('Hotel_Reviews.csv',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
object.size(df)
```

> 210584168 bytes

```
object.size(df[sample(1:nrow(df),500),])
```

> 394464 bytes

Comment: Yeah, one of my least favorite R defaults is that `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. I can see it being useful, but more often than not it's a pain in the neck for me. Well done finding the solution yourself and sharing for others